# How can i execute stop script after i run electron application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, electron

I have created a small [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) application which needs a small local [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community) (community version) database.

Now I need to configure the `start` and `stop` scripts inside my `package.json` so that every time I issue `npm start` NPM first starts my MongoDB and once started runs my Electron application.

Currently my `scripts` section in my `package.json` looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "stop": "mongodb/bin/mongo admin --eval 'db.shutdownServer()'",
  "prestart": "mongodb/bin/mongod --dbpath mongodb/data/db --fork --logpath logs/mongodb/mongolog.txt",
  "start": "electron . --fork > logs/mylog/mylog.txt"
}
```

The `start` and `prestart` scripts run just like I intended, but it seems that the `stop` script does not get executed once my Electron app closes or I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

How can I achieve that when I close my Electron application or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> that my MongoDB server also shutsdown?

Comment: can you maybe capture the `SIGINT`, like `process.on('SIGINT', function() { //cleanup });`

Answer (score 2):

Just like the `start` script in the `package.json`, the `stop` script will [only be executed if you issue `npm stop`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/stop) in your command line.

With Electron, you can detect when the app is going to close using `app.on()` in your main process script. There are two events which are relevant here: [`before-quit`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-before-quit), which will execute just *before* Electron will close all windows and [`will-quit`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-will-quit), which will be issued *after* Electron closed all browser windows. Both events will be fired when your app quits because all the windows got closed, and when Electron receives a `SIGINT` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

Using one of these two events, you will then be able to run the command you were trying to run using NPM:

```
const { exec } = require ("child_process");

// ...all of your main process' code...

app.on ("before-quit", (event) => {
  exec ("mongodb/bin/mongo admin --eval 'db.shutdownServer()'");
  process.exit (); // really let the app exit now
});
```

Comment: I did my own research and came across following `npm` module: [node-run-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-run-cmd) it was last published 2 years ago, but worked very well for my purpose. Using this module, i execute two commands: `'mongodb/bin/mongod --dbpath mongodb/data/db --logpath logs/mongodb/mongolog.txt'` and `'mongodb/bin/mongo localhost/admin --eval "db.shutdownServer()"'` instead of modifying the scripts inside `package.json` and everything seems to work as i intended so far. Thank you.